# Layout doesn`t work on fragment inflation

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

I am parsing an activity to a fragment, and that so i want to use Navigation Component from JetPack, so i created the graph, the fragment and copy and paste my layout to the fragment layout and create the navigation, but now i am getting an error trying to inflate the same layout that was already working.

I tested other fragment and it worked, so it is not the activity, i let just the inflation of the fragments layout and get the same error. what make me think, by elimination, that could be a problem on fragment layout.

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.MenuItem
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
import com.quicktendr.mgmt.androidApp.R
import com.quicktendr.mgmt.androidApp.databinding.ActivityManagementBinding
import com.quicktendr.mgmt.androidApp.ui.screen.OrdersFragment

class ManagementActivity : AppCompatActivity(),
BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityManagementBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityManagementBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        startFragment()
    }

    private fun startFragment() {
        setFragmentOnHost(OrdersFragment())
    }

    private fun setFragmentOnHost(fragment: Fragment) {
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.nav_host_fragment, fragment)
            .commit()
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        binding.bottomNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)
    }

    override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        when(item.itemId) {
            R.id.menu_order -> setFragmentOnHost(OrdersFragment())
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

The Fragment:

```
class OrdersFragment : Fragment() {

    private val viewModel: RestaurantViewModel by lazy {
        ViewModelProvider(this).get(
            RestaurantViewModel::class.java
        )
    }

    private lateinit var binding: FragmentOrdersBinding

    private var paused: Boolean = true

    private val activityContext = requireActivity()

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        binding = FragmentOrdersBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }
}
```

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.quicktendr.mgmt.androidApp, PID: 28706
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.quicktendr.mgmt.androidApp/com.quicktendr.mgmt.androidApp.ui.ManagementActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:439)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: androidx.fragment.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.quicktendr.mgmt.androidApp.ui.screen.OrdersFragment: calling Fragment constructor caused an exception
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:628)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainer.instantiate(FragmentContainer.java:57)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$3.instantiate(FragmentManager.java:483)
        at androidx.navigation.fragment.FragmentNavigator.instantiateFragment(FragmentNavigator.java:132)
        at androidx.navigation.fragment.FragmentNavigator.navigate(FragmentNavigator.java:162)
        at androidx.navigation.fragment.FragmentNavigator.navigate(FragmentNavigator.java:58)
        at androidx.navigation.NavGraphNavigator.navigate(NavGraphNavigator.java:71)
        at androidx.navigation.NavGraphNavigator.navigate(NavGraphNavigator.java:28)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:1059)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.onGraphCreated(NavController.java:639)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.setGraph(NavController.java:592)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.setGraph(NavController.java:557)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.setGraph(NavController.java:539)
        at androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment.onCreate(NavHostFragment.java:248)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2936)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.create(FragmentStateManager.java:472)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:278)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.onCreateView(FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.java:141)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:135)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:313)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:292)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:780)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at com.quicktendr.mgmt.androidApp.databinding.ActivityManagementBinding.inflate(ActivityManagementBinding.java:44)
        at com.quicktendr.mgmt.androidApp.databinding.ActivityManagementBinding.inflate(ActivityManagementBinding.java:38)
        at com.quicktendr.mgmt.androidApp.ui.ManagementActivity.onCreate(ManagementActivity.kt:20)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6999)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6990)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:439)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:610)
            ... 42 more
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment OrdersFragment{88e14c1} (b9e50338-6a7b-49ea-9d09-0cd62aec3759)} not attached to an activity.
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.requireActivity(Fragment.java:926)
        at com.quicktendr.mgmt.androidApp.ui.screen.OrdersFragment.<init>(OrdersFragment.kt:49)
            ... 45 more
```

and finally the possible problem, the fragments layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.screen.OrdersFragment">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/cl_restaurant_header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#c20000"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
                android:layout_width="500dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="12dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/til_restaurant_list"
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="8dp"
                    android:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
                    app:boxStrokeColor="@android:color/transparent"
                    app:endIconTint="@android:color/white">

                    <AutoCompleteTextView
                        android:id="@+id/actv_restaurant_list"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:inputType="none"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="24sp" />
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/cl_order_restaurant_actions"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/cl_restaurant_header"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/view_list_label">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/til_search_order"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_baseline_search_24"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                >

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/cl_add_subtract_time"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="42dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                >
                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/btn_subtract_time"
                    android:layout_width="42dp"
                    android:layout_height="42dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/round_button_shape"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_subtract"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/tv_minutes"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_minutes"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:textSize="22sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginHorizontal="8dp"
                    tools:text="45'"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/btn_subtract_time"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btn_add_time"
                    />
                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/btn_add_time"
                    android:layout_width="42dp"
                    android:layout_height="42dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/round_button_shape"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_add_24"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tv_minutes"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    />
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_play_pause"
                android:layout_width="42dp"
                android:layout_height="42dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="36dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_play_arrow_24"
                android:background="@drawable/round_button"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view_list_label"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="#F4D8D7"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/cl_order_restaurant_actions"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/cl_order_restaurant_actions" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_label_order_num"
            style="@style/OrderTextLabel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/view_list_label"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/gl_order_num_to_type"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/view_list_label" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_label_type"
            style="@style/OrderTextLabel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/view_list_label"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/gl_type_to_user"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/gl_order_num_to_type"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/view_list_label" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_label_user"
            style="@style/OrderTextLabel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/view_list_label"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/gl_user_to_state"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/gl_type_to_user"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/view_list_label" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_label_state"
            style="@style/OrderTextLabel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/view_list_label"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/gl_state_to_value"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/gl_user_to_state"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/view_list_label" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_label_value"
            style="@style/OrderTextLabel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/view_list_label"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/gl_value_to_delivery_hour"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/gl_state_to_value"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/view_list_label" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_label_delivery_hour"
            style="@style/OrderTextLabel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/view_list_label"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/gl_delivery_hour_to_action"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/gl_value_to_delivery_hour"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/view_list_label" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_label_action"
            style="@style/OrderTextLabel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/view_list_label"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/gl_delivery_hour_to_action"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/view_list_label" />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_order_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/view_list_label" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/gl_order_num_to_type"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.125" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/gl_type_to_user"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.22" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/gl_user_to_state"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.45" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/gl_state_to_value"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.59" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/gl_value_to_delivery_hour"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.68" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/gl_delivery_hour_to_action"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.8" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Again the same layout was working before, when was used in a activity.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the

```
private val activityContext = requireActivity()
```

in your `OrdersFragment`. The fragment is not yet attached to any activity at init phase, causing the exception, and storing the activity reference to a field is redundant and prone to memory leaks anyway.